# mostrar saldo en funcion de ingreso o retirada

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una simulación de cajero automático y no se como evaluar en este switch para que muestre el saldo en funcion de dinero ingresado o retirado. La clase que veis es la del menú de inicio que es donde se desarrolla la interfaz de usuario. Me he quedado atascado en el case 3 del switch sé que asi no funciona porque **opciones** vale 3 al entrar. Y claro solo si no lo hago así solo podría poner o el saldo resultante del ingreso o el saldo resultante de la retirada. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
public class Menu {

    private static Scanner sc;
    private static int opciones;
    private static final int SALIR = 4;
    private static double ingreso;
    private static double retirada;
    private static double saldo;

    public static void mostrarMenu() {

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            Mensaje.mostrarMensajeMenuPrincipal();
            opciones = sc.nextInt();

            switch (opciones) {

            case 1:
                Mensaje.mostrarMensajeIngreso();
                ingreso = sc.nextDouble();
                Transaccion.setIngreso(ingreso);
                ingreso = Transaccion.getIngreso() + Cuenta.getSaldoInicial();
                saldo = ingreso;
                break;

            case 2:
                Mensaje.mostrarMensajeRetirada();
                retirada = sc.nextDouble();
                Transaccion.setRetirada(retirada);
                double retiradaCuenta = ingreso - Transaccion.getRetirada();
                saldo = retiradaCuenta;
                break;

            case 3:

                if (opciones == 1) {

                    Cuenta.setSaldoInicial();
                    double saldo = Cuenta.getSaldoInicial();
                    saldo = saldo + ingreso;
                    Mensaje.mostrarMensajeSaldo(saldo);

                } else if (opciones == 2) {

                    Cuenta.setSaldoInicial();
                    double saldo = Cuenta.getSaldoInicial();
                    saldo = ingreso - retirada;
                    Mensaje.mostrarMensajeSaldo(saldo);
                }
                

                break;

            case 4:
                Mensaje.mostrarMensajeSalir();
                break;

            default:
                Mensaje.mostrarMensajeDefault();
            }

        } while (opciones != SALIR);

    }

}
```

Comment: El saldo lo actualizas al hacer el ingreso o la retirada, al mostrar el saldo muestras el valor sin importante de dónde sale.

Comment: "para que muestre el saldo en funcion de dinero ingresado o retirado." Con esto te refieres a que tu programa imprima por consola el saldo actual luego de haber retirado o haber ingresado dinero?

Comment: No entiendo todo el lío que tienes de variables. Solo tienes que guardar el saldo actual, que inicializas a 0. En cada ingreso le sumas el importe, en cada retiro se lo restas. Y solo guardas el valor actual. Por otro lado, ¿qué debería hacer el case 3? ¿Mostrar el saldo? Pues ya, lo tenga la variable porque ya tiene que estar siempre actualizada.

Comment: Andres Gardiol si eso es.

Comment: es que es la primera vez que empiezo un proyecto solo y me voy liando yo solo a medida que voy avanzando y acabo bloqueandome.

Comment: Pues no te líes que no hay necesidad y es muy sencillo. Solo defines el Saldo actual. En el case 1, pides el importe a ingresar, lo guardas en una variable temporal definida ahí mismo en el case y eso se lo sumas a la única variable que tiene tu clase referente al dinero que es el Saldo. En el case 2 lo mismo pero restando en vez de sumando. Y el en case 3 muestras el valor que tenga saldo. Si entras nada más empezar en el case 3, si inicializas Saldo a 0, te dirá que el saldo es 0. Haces un ingreso, vuelves al case 3 y te dirá que el Saldo es: lo que hayas ingresado.

Comment: Muchas gracias SuperG280 y a los que habeis arrojado un poco de luz a esto, no se si al final me enredo tanto por falta de planificación antes o porque no se me da o por las dos cosas jaja, pero gracias un saludo chicos.